# Angularjs blueimp fileUpload - file-upload change event not working

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, blueimp

How do I trigger `$scope.$on` on *fileupload* change.

**.html**

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

**.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['blueimp.fileupload', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.$on('fileuploadchange', function (event, files) {
            debugger
            $scope.Files = files.files;
        });    
}
```

I try to show a list of selected files using `$scope.Files` before uploading just like this screenshot..but file-upload change event is not working

[image]